# Workday OAuth 2.0 - unable to get authorization code

Tags: oauth-2.0, workday-api

I am trying to leverage the Workday REST Api and am trying to follow the authorization code grant flow listed here (https://community.workday.com/rest/oauth).

However I am getting stuck sending a GET authorization request to the authorization endpoint in Postman.

I send a request like this:

`GET /authorize?response_type=code&client_id=ODQ4ZDdkNzItMzhiMC00YmFmLTgyNzAtNzljNjM0MDlmNmY2`

But I get what looks like a Workday login webpage back in postman. When I try and access this via a browser, I get the Workday login page and login but nothing happens. I am expecting to get an Authorization code back somewhere.

What am I missing here?